# Python program that takes test scores and outputs the following:

Tags: python

I have to write a program that takes test scores entered by the user and outputs, all the entered scores, the average score, the largest and lowest score, all the scores over 50, and all the scores over the average. Im getting an error where scores is not identified, im not sure what im doing wrong calling the list? I'm still new to programming and am struggling with calling functions. thanks.

```
def main():
    test = getscores()
    avg = average(test)
    top = large(test)
    over = passed(test)
    greater = above(test, avg)

    print("The test scores are,", test)
    print("The average test score is,", avg)
    print("The largest and lowest score are," top)
    print("All the PASS scores are,", over)
    print("All the scores above average are,", greater)

def getscores():
    scores = []     
    xStr = input("Enter a test score in the range 0-100: (<Enter> to quit)")
    while xStr != "":
        x = eval(xStr)
        scores.append(x)   
        xStr = input("Enter a test score int he range 0-100: (<Enter> to quit)")
    return scores

def average(scores):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in scores:
        sum = sum + scores
        avg = sum / i
    return avg

def large(scores):
    largest = max(scores)
    lowest = min(scores)
    return largest, lowest

def passed(scores):
    for i in scores:
        PASS = i > 50
    return PASS

def above(scores, avg):
    high = scores > avg
    return high

main()
```

Comment: I don't see a question. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I'm not getting that error. In fact I got a syntax error on the line `print("The largest and lowest score are," top)` because you omitted a comma. Even after fixing that I get a completely different error. Are you sure you pasted your exact code?

Comment: The error I'm getting is that the you're trying to add a float to a list, on this line: `sum = sum + scores` because `sum` is a float and `scores` is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a list here:

---

You probably *don't* want to call `eval()` to enter the values, when `int()` is a much better alternative. The former is for evaluation arbitrary expressions such as `1 + 2` or `variable * 7`.

---

In addition, if you're using Python 2, you want `raw_input()` rather than `input()`.

---

In your `average` function, there's no need to work out the average until you have the complete sum. On top of that, you are trying to add an integer `sum` with a list `scores` whereas you should be adding the element of `scores`, which is `i`. Rewrite that as:

```
def average(scores):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in scores:
        sum = sum + i
    avg = sum / len(scores)
    return avg
```

---

Since `large()` returns two values, and you want to print both, you should call it as:

```
(top, bottom) = large(test)
```

and print it with something like:

```
print("The largest and lowest score are ", top, " and ", bottom)
```

---

Your `passed()` function returns a single truth value rather than a number of people passed. It could be written as:

```
def passed(scores):
    quant = 0
    for i in scores:
        if i > 50:
            quant = quant + 1
    return quant
```

---

Same deal with the `above()` function, which would be better as:

```
def above(scores,avg):
    quant = 0
    for i in scores:
        if i > avg:
            quant = quant + 1
    return quant
```

---

With all those changes made, you'll see something along the lines of:

```
Enter a test score in the range 0-100: (<Enter> to quit)52
Enter a test score int he range 0-100: (<Enter> to quit)45
Enter a test score int he range 0-100: (<Enter> to quit)8
Enter a test score int he range 0-100: (<Enter> to quit)
('The test scores are,', [52, 45, 8])
('The average test score is,', 35.0)
('The largest and lowest score are', 52, 'and', 8)
('All the PASS scores are,', 1)
('All the scores above average are,', 2)
```

---

If you want to return an actual *list* of passing and above-average scores, you can construct such a list and append to it, exactly as you've done when *entering* the scores:

```
def passed(scores):
    slist = []
    for i in scores:
        if i > 50:
            slist.append(i)
    return slist

def above(scores,avg):
    slist = []
    for i in scores:
        if i > avg:
            slist.append(i)
    return slist
```

Or better yet, refactor so you only need *one:*

```
def above(scores,threshold):
    slist = []
    for i in scores:
        if i > threshold:
            slist.append(i)
    return slist

over = above(test,50)
greater = above(test, avg)
```

Comment: awesome works great, but for the passed and average scores i need it to return the actual scores over 50 and greater then the average, respectively, i changed them to do this but i can only get it to return one of the scores, how do i make it return multiple scores over the average or over 50

Comment: @John, the same way you returned the highest and lowest scores, I'll update the answer.

Comment: thats great, thank you very much, i was actually alot closer then i thought, very reassuring.

Comment: @John, you were. Despite the long list, the items were fairly minor in nature and your code was thorough. You may also want to consider an upvote to reverse the drive-by downvoter. I'm anal retentive enough that it irks me to have an accepted answer with negative score :-)

Comment: i would upvote you believe me but i sadly dont have the reputation to do so, it says i need 15 and i only have 8.